# JAX-RS, how to prevent user A from accessing user B's restful resource

Tags: security, rest, authorization, jax-rs, glassfish-3

I'm using JAX-RS on Glassfish to implement a set of resources, which can be accessed only by specific users.

Consider two users, userA and userB, both registered in my website.

1. userA created its own resource `http://{localhost}/service/user/A`;
2. userB created its own resource `http://{localhost}/service/user/B`;

Then Glassfish's default security implementation was configured as:

1. User Role can access `/services/user/*`
2. userA and userB are both in User Role.

So when logged in, both userA and userB can access to `/service/user/A` and `/service/user/B`.

Now the question, 
Is it possible that

- userA can only access `/services/user/A`, but not `/services/user/B`

and at the same time

- userB can only access `/services/user/B, but not`/services/user/A`

I think I must have missed something, because this is a common need I believe.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is something that you have to implement at the application level. The application server has no way to know about your security policy, which could be quite sophisticated. You could do it yourself (adding logic in User resource), and that might be the right approach if your security policy is simple. Otherwise, you should look at Spring Security, which can be integrated with JAX-RS. That will give you a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Thanks Olivier. And yes, I've tried to add some authorization logic in the User resource, the logic was to compare **userid** in the **request's URL** and **request's user principle**. But this also makes the User resource class complicated, because it combined the authorization logic into a typical resource. So I guess I should try Spring Security then.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I don't have authority to Vote Up you. Sorry about that. By the way, Olivier, is there any other way around that's more lightweight than Spring Security?

Answer (score 0):

After searching around, it seems it is not trivial to solve the problem above using the JAX-RS and JAAS.

So I decide to take a look at **OAuth**, to see if authorization could be easily handled.

After hours reading I started to realize what Olivier was talking about. What I wanted is to bind user identity to the URI. But JAAS or OAuth is really designed to solve other problems.

1. **JAAS**, or Role based authentication system is designed to authorize a set of users to access a set of URIs. It's like a room full of toys, once a user plays a roommate ROLE, this user has the key to the room, then he can play with every toy in the room or even destroy all of them. If you want to label each toy with a user's name and stop them from playing with other people's toy, you need to implement the logic outside of JAAS.
2. **OAuth**, even worse. It is not even related to binding between user and URI. It is dedicated on letting a 3rd party valet software using your data with limited access. Consider the room-toy story about JAAS, you want the window in the room be opened, but you don't have time for this. So you hired a valet, and made a valet key for him to access the room, open the window, and at the same time, stay away from the toys. The magic part about OAuth is, the valet is given just enough resource to complete master's assignment, and more importantly, the room knows whom sent the valet by recognizing the valet key.

Now from a developer's view, you may ask why the valet can access the window but not the toys; in other words, how to let the 3rd party software access some URI but not other URIs? This is not handled by OAuth. OAuth only tells you Oh, this is Bob's valet, and for everything else, you are on your own.

It is not totally a bad thing about OAuth, it gives you the opportunity to decide what ROLE this valet has, or which URI can this kind of valet access, or what resources can Bob's valet access, etc.

Hope this would help anyone reading save some time. And please don't blame me about the poor story, I struggled 1 hour to make the story simpler. :)

Comment: If you try to implement OAuth yourself, it will not be easier. So you should use a library for that. This is also one of the capabilities of the Spring Framework, by the way. Having said that, OAuth will not answer your original question (scoping the access to data, based on the user identity). OAuth is useful if you have a service A (e.g. Instagram) that manages user data and if you want that the user can authorize another service B (e.g. Postagram, which prints instragram photos) to access the Service A data. The logic needed to answer your question should not be that difficult.

Comment: Yes, Olivier, you are definitely right. I updated my post. Hmm, I'm looking back into JAX-RS to see if any solution exists. Any ideas there?

Comment: The last update. The question here is, by jEE 6's specification, out of the scope of security, and should be handled in other places. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaay.html

Comment: @Xiangyu, have you found another solution inside the JEE spec or have you ended up using Spring Security anyway?

Comment: @BrunoGasparotto I'm now using spring boot with security, it is really common these days. If you chose java, there's nothing else worth struggling with.